# Manage permissions in a Symfony application

Tags: php, symfony, permissions, user-permissions

I'm looking for a solution for managing the permissions in an application. Let's say I have a website in which you can post comments or edit them.
For example I want my users to be able to:
USER1: post a comment and edit
USER2: only post a comment
USER3: edit other people's comments

Is there anything available according to my needs? I searched for a bundle who can do what I want but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html You can solve this with role hierarchy

Answer (score 2):

I think [Standard SYmfony security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) will be enough